# How to define big system of similar ODEs inside ParametricNDSolveValue?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

My question seems extremely simple but I cannot find a solution.

I have a system of ODEs of the form $u_i'(t) = f(t,i,pars)$, where pars are some parameters - the same for all $u_i$ apart from one which is dependent on $t$. After getting multiple errors, as a test, for simplification, I decided to try with the following easy system:

$u_i'(t) = par\cdot i\cdot u(t) \quad \text{with} \quad  u_i(0) = 0, \quad \forall i\in[iMin,iMax]$.

What I tried was the following:

```
iMin=0;  
iMax=10;
space=Range[iMin,iMax];
modelTest = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  (* equation *)
  {
  u'[t] == par*#*u[t]&/@Range[Length[space]],
  u[t /; t<=0] == ConstantArray[0,Length[space]]
  },
  (* solution components to return *)
  u,
  (* time interval *)
  {t,0,100},
  (* parameters *)
  {par}
];
```

I would expect it then to behave the same as having a system of `Length[space]`-many ODEs which it should solve. However, it just gives me an error saying that the system is overdetermined (`There are fewer dependent variables, {u[t]}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined`). What am I missing?

I previously tried to define them with a `For` loop but that didn't work either. Could you please give me any suggestion on how to do this? I want to define this in order to evaluate parameters with manipulate and later on to estimate them.

Looking forward to your answers!

Comment: I wonder if you perhaps oversimplified your example. In this case, it does seem that you have too many equations for the same one function `u[t]`. In fact, don't those equations imply that either $par=0$ or `u[t]` is constant as written?

Comment: Yes, of course it is an oversimplified example, but my question is not mathematical. My question is why can't I use ``Range[]`` as I did in order to make a list of ODEs defined depending on their index $i$. How do I define a system of ODEs (in the form of a list) for which the right hand sides are similar in the form $f(i,u(t),par)$ with $i$ being integer in a certain range? The point of oversimplifying was to see if the error came from my $f$ (in the original complicated problem) or from some other reason. And it seems to me that the reason is this ``Range[]``... So how else should I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
iMin = 0;
iMax = 10;
eq = Table[u[i]'[t] == -i*u[i][t] + a, {i, iMin, iMax}];
ic = Table[u[i][0] == 1, {i, iMin, iMax}];
s = Table[u[i][t], {i, iMin, iMax}];
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, ic}, s, {t, 0, 1}, {a}];
{Plot[sol[0], {t, 0, 1}], Plot[sol[.5], {t, 0, 1}]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought of making $i$ an argument as well when I tried the ``For`` but I wasn't sure how to write the LHS of the ODE (``u[i]'[t]``). And of course ``Table`` is a much better choice than ``For``. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

[Alex](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/58388/alex-trounev) has shown a solution based on expressing $u$ as an explicit list, the following is an alternative solution treating $u$ as an implicit list:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[i_, u_List, par_] := -i u + par
(* Alternatively: *)
(*
   f = Compile[{{i, _Real, 1}, {u, _Real, 1}, par}, -i u + par, 
               RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False];
 *)

ilst = Table[i, {i, iMin, iMax}];
eqvec = u'[t] == f[ilst, u[t], a];
icvec = u[0] == Table[1, {i, iMin, iMax}];
solvec = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqvec, icvec}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {a}];
Plot[solvec[0][t] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}]
Plot[solvec[.5][t] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}]
```

The resulting graph is the same so I'd like to omit it here.

The main advantage of this method is, it's memory saving when the ODE system is really large.